# Read different sections of a string

Tags: swift, string

I store some files in file manager and I need three data string in their name that I can do the necessary modification, they data I need are two ids and one timestamp, something like that

```
"hdh3npHvjjkdfydlz-jfoabcotmdbnadp-1657155181"
```

I want to read each of them separately, those three data is separated by one - and the number of the characters may be not the same for different files. Can anyone help me to do that?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1413214-components should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to extract each piece of info from the string using a hyphen as a delimiter?  If so, you could use:

```
import UIKit

let myString = "hdh3npHvjjkdfydlz-jfoabcotmdbnadp-1657155181"
let components = myString.components(separatedBy: "-")

for c in components {
    print(c)
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
let items = myString.split(separator: "-")

for i in items {
    print(i)
}
```

Either one will separate the string into individual pieces using the hyphen as a delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

You can split a `String` variable in parts by using the `components` function, like this:

```
let example = "hdh3npHvjjkdfydlz-jfoabcotmdbnadp-1657155181"
let parts = example.components(separatedBy: "-")
for part in parts {
    // Do your thing
}
```